# Smallest number of people that has birthday today exceeds 1/2

Tags: probability

Find the smallest number of people you need to choose
at random so that the probability that at least one of them
has a birthday today exceeds 1/2.

My Approach/Attempt-:

$P\left ( No\, \, one\, \,  born \, \, today \right )+P\left ( atleast \, \, one\, \,  born\, \,  today \right )=1$
$P\left ( atleast\, \, one\, \,  born \, \, today \right )=1-P\left ( No\, \,  one\, \,  born\, \,  today \right )$

$P\left ( atleast \, \, one \, \, born\, \,  today \right )$=$1-\left ( 364/365 \right )^{n}$

Answer will be $1-\left ( 364/365 \right )^{n}\geq 1/2$

how to solve $1-\left ( 364/365 \right )^{n}\geq 1/2$   and then find n?

Comment: This assumes that nobody are born on Februrary 29, I suppose?

Comment: Yep ,assume no leap year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few steps:
$$1−(364/365)^n\geq 1/2$$
$$1/2=1−1/2\geq (364/365)^n$$
$$\log(1/2)\geq n\log(364/365)$$
$$\log(2)\leq n(\log(365/364))$$
Can you take it form here?

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange to
$$ 1 - 1/2 \ge (364/365)^n $$
and take logarithms on both sides.